# TablePanelLayout last row seems to grow each time I refresh it?

Tags: vb.net

Each time I run this code to add controls to the TableLayoutPanel, the last row seems to keep growing, I can't understand why.

```
InfoWindow.RowStyles.Clear()
InfoWindow.Controls.Clear()
InfoWindow.RowCount = 0


        For i As Integer = 0 To TextLines.Count - 8
            InfoWindow.RowCount += 1
            InfoWindow.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
            label = New Label With {.AutoSize = True, .Text = TextLines(i).Substring(0, TextLines(i).IndexOf("|")).Trim}
            InfoWindow.Controls.Add(label, 0, InfoWindow.RowCount - 1)

            label = New Label With {.AutoSize = True, .Text = TextLines(i).Substring(TextLines(i).IndexOf("|") + 1).Trim}
            InfoWindow.Controls.Add(label, 1, InfoWindow.RowCount - 1)
        Next
```

The first time I run this code, it looks fine. If I run the code again, the last row gets bigger and bigger. It looks something like this after I run the code a few times...

[image]

Where in my code is it making the last row bigger? I'm stumped.

I made sure to clear out the rows by setting it to 0, I clear out the rowstyles as well and the controls, but why is the last row getting bigger and bigger each time?

Comment: Where does that code run?

Comment: I run this code inside a button

Comment: I add labels to the LayoutPanelTable and give the label some text. The LayoutPanel only has 2 columns. Everything is set to autosize.

Comment: This is not heading the right way, you are writing code that's going to crash on the user's machine.  It hasn't happen on yours yet because you haven't tested it long enough.  TLP must never be used to implement a grid control, it is only suitable for layout.  Use DataGridView if stuff needs to be editable, LlistView with View = Details if not.

Comment: I'm not really using it as a GridControl but it really does seem like it huh? I guess I could convert over to DataGridView, I just wanted to use TLP because it automatically aligns everything for me to look neat. That TLP you see is actually for a popup when a user hover over something. I guess if I use a DataGridView, I don't have to create 10 or so controls and the data will just be in 1 control

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's because the TableLayoutPanel dock was set to FILL. Set it to none and it was normal height again